# How to format a string in python to use a list

Tags: python, formatting, multiline

I have the following piece of code:

```
import textwrap
text_string = "This is a long string that goes beyond 40 characters"

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=40)
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=text_string)
year = '2018'
pkg = 'textwrap'
new_string = """This is a new string formatted in {1} with {2} resulting in 
{3}""".format(year, pkg, *word_list)
```

If I were to run this piece of code here is what I observed:
{3} is replaced with the first element of word_list. Since I don't know the size of word_list I wanted {3} to take each member of the list on to a new line. and string new line should be:

""" This is a new string formatted in 2018 with textwrap resulting in
This is a long string that goes beyond 4
0 characters"""

but instead it becomes
""" This is a new string formatted in 2018 with textwrap resulting in
This is a long string that goes beyond 4

I couldn't determine how I could use format to accomplish this. I am not trying to print this and I dont want to insert '\n' because this new string gets appened to a file and not goign to be printed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The output did not get formatted right. - I expected two lines for the list the first one ending with 4 and the second line starting with 0 with 40 characters for each member of the list but I get only one member of the list printed.

Comment: Your code works here. Or maybe I don't understand your expected output?

Comment: I notice you have a question which has an answer (which you commented on as a solution to your problem). Remember for this or any other question, you should [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem. This increases both your and the person who answered reputation and allows future visitors to know that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `join` on the list to turn it into a string comprised of all the elements in the list separated by a delimiter:

```
new_string = """This is a new string formatted in {1} with {2} resulting in 
{3}""".format(year, pkg, " ".join(word_list))
```

Comment: I cannot use word_list.join (' ") - I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: There is such method as list.join

Comment: That is correct so it goes back to how can I format new_string to take a list in the original question

Comment: You can do: 

' '.join(word_list)

Comment: @user9906612 Mixed up the order, sorry. It's been a while since I regularly worked in python.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, then two ways to do what you want are:

#### 1. Continue to use the wrap call to return a list

So we still are using the wrap method to return a list, in this case we will just have to build a string in the format as passing `*args` to format (called [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)) requires a known length. Such:

```
import textwrap
text_string = "This is a long string that goes beyond 40 characters"

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=40)
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=text_string)

year = '2018'
pkg = 'textwrap'
new_string = """This is a new string formatted in {} with {} resulting in""".format(year,pkg)
new_string += str("\n{}" * len(word_list)).format(*word_list)

#originally had above using join but this method can increase performance if text is large
#join version: new_string = """This is a new string formatted in {} with {} resulting in \n{}""".format(year,pkg,"\n".join(word_list))


print(new_string)
```

I created the base string (`new_string`) then concated that with a new string (`\n{}`) which I multiplied as many times as there were elements in the list `word_list` - creating the needed number of `{}`s in the string for format with an unpacked word_list.

#### 2. Use the "[fill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.fill)" method to just build a wrapped string

Note: here I use a dictionary as I personally think this is cleaner when passing values to format but you can change that back if not needed.

```
import textwrap
text_string = "This is a long string that goes beyond 40 characters"
#Using a dictionary to create a map for passing
results_dict = {
    "year": "2018",
    "pkg": "textwrap",
    "word_list": ""
}

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=40)

results_dict["word_list"] = wrapper.fill(text=text_string)

new_string = """This is a new string formatted in {year} with {pkg} resulting in \n{word_list}""".format(**results_dict)
#using the **results_dict as a map just to show another method for format
print(new_string)
```

In this case, fill just returns a wrapped version (string) of the given paragraph or sentence so we just need to pass that as normally.

### Output of both:

```
This is a new string formatted in 2018 with textwrap resulting in
This is a long string that goes beyond
40 characters
```